# Is the Cantor Pairing function guaranteed to generate a unique real number for all real numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, real-numbers, integers

I recently learned that for natural numbers, the Cantor Pairing function allows one to output a unique natural number from any combination of two natural numbers. According to wikipedia, it is a computable bijection
$$f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$$
$$f(x,y) := \frac 12 (x+y)(x+y+1)+y$$
Will it generate a unique value for all real (non-integer) number values of $x$ and $y$? I believe there is no inverse function if using non-integer inputs, but I just want to know if the output $f(x,y)$ will still be unique.

Please forgive me if this isn't a worthwhile question, I do not have a mathematics background.

Edit: I'm interested in the case where we constrain $x$ and $y$ to real numbers $>0$.

Comment: This might help : The first summand is equal to the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $x+y$

Comment: Yes, *every* function generates a unique output for all inputs. For example, the function $f(x,y):=3$ generates the unique number $3$ for all $x$ and $y.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even for positive reals the answer is no, the result is not unique.  You can choose any $x,y,$ compute $f(x,y)$, then choose any $x'\lt x$  and solve $\frac 12(x'+y')(x'+y'+1)+y'=f(x,y)$ for $y'$  The only reason for the $x'$ restriction is to make sure you get a positive square root.  For example, let $x=3,y=5,x'=2$.  We have $f(3,5)=41$ so want $\frac 12(2+y')(3+y')+y'=41$, which has solutions $y'=\frac 12(-7\pm\sqrt{353})\approx -12.8941,5.8941$ so $f(3,5)=f(2,\frac 12(-7+\sqrt{353}))$ in the positive reals.  You can allow any of $x,y,x'$ to be other than integers.  $y'$ will usually not be integral.

Comment: Very clear and illuminating response, thank you.

Comment: Actually, if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, $f(x,y)=\frac12(x+y)(x+y+1)+y$ *is* a unique real number. That's what it means for $f$ to be a function.

Comment: @bof:  that is true, but in the naturals there is no other pair $(x',y')$ that results in the same value of $f$.  In the naturals, given a value $f(x,y)$ you can uniquely determine $x$ and $y$.  That is not true in the reals, which was what OP asked.  I demonstrated a case where you cannot determine $x$ and $y$ from $f(x,y)$

Answer (score 2):

A function on two variables $x$ and $y$ is called a *polynomial function* if it is defined by a formula built up from $x$, $y$ and numeric constants (like $0, 1, 2, \ldots$) using addition,multiplication. So Cantor's pairing function is a polynomial function.

If $f(x, y)$ is a polynomial function, then $f$ cannot be an injection of $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}$ into $\Bbb{R}$ (because of [o-minimality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory)).

Comment: Ah, interesting thanks. What if I constrain x,y to rational numbers > 0?

Comment: Constraining $x$ and $y$ to rational numbers won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $f(-1,1)=f(-2,1)$

Comment: Thank you. I should mention I actually only care for real values > 0. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: $-1$ and $-2$ are not natural numbers.